# Rails scope based on range of time of associated objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a performant scope that looks at a model's associated record's `starts_at` datetime, and fetch objects whose associated records fall within that window.

For example:

```
class Championship < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :races
end

class Race < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :championship
end
```

Each `Race` record has a `starts_at` timestamp. I need to look at each `Championship`'s Races, order those Races by `starts_at`, fetch the first one (chronologically) and check if we are PAST that time, and fetch the last one and check if we are PRIOR to that time.

```
class Championship < ApplicationRecord
  scope :active, -> { joins(:races)...? }
```

But I'm really not sure how to order these records in SQL and fetch the first or last record for evaluation.

**UPDATE (for clarification)**

```
c = Championship.create()
r1 = c.races.create(starts_at: '2021-05-01')
r2 = c.races.create(starts_at: '2021-06-01')
r3 = c.races.create(starts_at: '2021-07-01')
r4 = c.races.create(starts_at: '2021-08-01')
```

So let's say the current time is:

- 04/01/21: Championship should **not** be `active`
- 05/01/21: Championship should be be `active`
- 05/15/21: Championship should be be `active`
- 08/15/21: Championship should **not** be `active`

**UPDATE (resolution)**
Here's what we ended up with:

```
scope :active, -> { where(id: Race.select(:championship_id).group(:championship_id).having("MIN(races.starts_at) - interval '1 day' < ?", Time.now).having("MAX(races.starts_at) + interval '2 days' > ?", Time.now).pluck(:championship_id)) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to order your table!

```rb
class Championship < ApplicationRecord
  def self.active
    condition = Races
      .select(:championship_id)
      .group(:championship_id)
      .having('min(races.starts_at) <= ?', date)
      .having('max(races.starts_at) >= ?', date)
    joins(:races).merge(condition)
  end

  (...)
end
```

PS: if you have a performance issue you can add an index on this column with
`rails generate migration add_index_to_races_starts_at`. It should generate the following migration:

```rb
class AddIndexToRacesStartsAt < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_index :products, :part_number
  end
end
```

Comment:  wow, I think I was desperately overthinking this!  I will try this out later tonight to confirm. Thanks for the gracious knock over the head.

Comment: Leonard, actually this does not work. Let me try to explain. Let's say a Championship runs 6 months, with 1 race every month. If we do a range like you suggested, that Championship would only be considered "Active" within a very small window when a race starts_at matches up with the current time. What we really need is to take a Championships races, from beginning to end, and see if we are within that window. Perhaps something like Championship.joins(:races).where("MIN(races.starts_at) < ?", Time.now - 1.day), but that's not valid...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want. Could you edit your post with a concrete example with dates, please?

Comment: Sure thing, sorry for not explaining this well. I just added an update which hopefully clears things up a bit?

Comment: Can you confirm that the updated query is fine?

Comment: I think that is getting me close, however this is what im getting returned: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Championship id: nil>, #<Championship id: nil>, #<Championship id: nil>]>` and I'd need the full object (not just id) (also not sure why the id is nil).

Comment: But a slight mod of that is seeming to work i think:

`champ_ids = Race.select(:championship_id).group(:championship_id).having('min(races.starts_at) >= ?', Time.now - 1.week).having('max(races.starts_at) <= ?', Time.now + 2.weeks).pluck(:championship_id)`

`Championship.where(id: champ_ids)`

Comment: I added another update with how we finally resolved it. Thanks so much for your help!